# Setting tab order with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page which has multiple forms. I'm using Mootools sliding tabs so each of the buttons on the menu slide along to the next form. There are 3 forms which are technically on the same HTML page. See an example of the technique at http://creativepony.com/archive/demos/sliding-tabs/

My problem is when a user presses the tab key and tabs through to the last field I want the tab order so it goes back to the first field. This is so the user does not accidentally tab to the next form. The user would end up looping back around the same form fields. For the user to reach the next form they use the menu so I don't want them to be able to tab to the next form.

I am aware of setting tab order with 'tabindex' but this doesn't help me make the user return to the first field of that form.

Any ideas how to achieve this with javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I would do this by making the fields in the forms that aren't visible `disabled`, so the browser knows to skip them, regardless of navigation mechanism (think accessibility aids).

Comment: Indeed, this looks to me like the best solution: if a user can't 'tab' their way to the second form, they can always just point and click there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via event listeners:

```
$$(".foo").addEvent("click", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 9) new Event(e).stop();
  $("#myfield").focus();
});
```

Comment: Is this a jQuery solution? If so, it doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: No, it uses MooTools. At least what I can remember from when I used to code MooTools 2 years ago.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the remark that the OP is using Mootools. I don't know that framework well, but is it really necessary to issue a `new Event` to stop the current one from propagating? And shouldn't you use the `keydown` event, instead of `click`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm fairly new to JS and Mootools and just wondered if you had an example of it in use. I presume the .foo class is placed on the last input field the #myfield id on the first? I'm using mootools 1.2.4 and not having much luck implementing this. I'm sure it's really simple to. I've also tried using $('input-element').addEvent('keydown', function(event){
  if (event.code==9 && !event.shift) {
    return false;
  }
}); but without success...